# Python Decimal to Binary Converter: "unsupported operand type(s) for /: 'str' and 'int'"

Tags: python, valueconverter

For a class project I have to make a Decimal to Hexadecimal or Binary Converter, and I keep on receiving

```
unsupported operand type(s)for /: 'str' and 'int'
```

and have no clue how to fix it

This is the rest of my code:

```
strOut = ""
def decimalToBinary():    
    while x != 0:
        decVal = str(x) / 2
        remainder = decVal % 2
        strOut = str(remainder) + strOut
        return strOut


print ("Do you want to:")
print ("(1) - Convert from Decimal to Binary")
print ("(2) - Convert from Decimal to Hexadecimal")
choice = raw_input("Enter the number of the function you would like to 
use! ")

if choice == "1":
    numChoice = raw_input("Enter the number you would like to 
    convert")
    x = numChoice
    decimalToBinary()
```

Thanks in advance!

Comment: So, you don’t have a clue how to fix it. But do you have a clue what the error could *maybe* tell you? Did you even attempt to understand what the error might be?

Comment: The error is saying "you can't divide a string by a number" , to make a division you need two numbers

Comment: `x` should be a parameter to `decimalToBinary`, not a global.

Comment: Also you should avoid using `x` as global variable but rather pass it to the function like so : `decimalToBinary(x)`

Answer (score 1):

`decVal = str(x) / 2` should be decVal = `decVal = float(x) / 2` to get rid of your error.

Comment: Using floating-point arithmetic for a base conversion seems like a bad idea, no?

Comment: I am answering the question regarding his error.  I don't want to do his homework. the variable name seems to imply he wanted a decimal.

Comment: "Decimal" here refers to base 10, not a fraction value after a decimal point.

Answer (score 0):

Python is strongly typed.

you are trying to divide a string by an integer here:

`decVal = str(x) / 2`

Comment: This diagnoses the problem; it does not fix it.

Comment: @chepner  I gave explanation for why the error is occuring.  That answers the question.  This is a question/answer site not an interactive debugger.

Comment: "I keep on receiving [...] and have no clue how to fix it". This answer provides no additional clue on how to fix it.

Comment: pointing out that it is strongly typed gives a very precise reason what is wrong.  Fixing it is an exercise left to the OP.  btw, feel free to downvote and post your own answer... that's sorta how it works here.

Comment: You are basically just restating the error message.

Comment: except the error message doesn't mention strong typing at all.  Again, if you believe my answer is of low quality, the proper course of action is to downvote it.

Answer (score 0):

> People often use the term strongly-typed language to refer to a
>   language that is both statically typed (types are associated with a
>   variable declaration -- or, more generally, the compiler can tell
>   which type a variable refers to, for example through type inference,
>   without executing the program) and strongly-typed (restrictive about
>   how types can be intermingled).

for more information read **[Why is Python a dynamic language and also a strongly typed language](https://wiki.python.org/moin/Why%20is%20Python%20a%20dynamic%20language%20and%20also%20a%20strongly%20typed%20language)**

and for your question, 
just change

`decVal = str(x) / 2`

to

```
decVal = float(x) / 2
```

Comment: I'm not sure what the (mistaken) belief that strongly-typed implies static typing has to do with the question. The OP seems aware that *some* sort of explicit type conversion is necessary, given the unnecessary call to `str(x)`.

Comment: @chepner i just explain why he can't devide string and integer, if you think that it's not necessary i can edit my answer